# tensorflow model is showing value error on may be initializers

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

```
model structure
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
#initializing with he_uniform
initializer3 = tf.keras.initializers.he_uniform(seed=30)

#creating model
model_3 = Sequential([
          InputLayer(input_shape = (2,),name = "input_layer"),
          Dense(50,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=initializer3,name = "Dense1"), 
                    
          Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer3, name = "Dense2"),
                    
          Dense(150, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer3, name = "Dense3"),
          Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer3, name = "Dense4"),
          Dense(250, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer3, name = "Dense5"),
          Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=initializer3, name = "OutputLayer")
])

#callbacks list
callback_list1 = [metrics_cb, checkpoint, terminate, earlystop, reduce_lr,lrschedule]


# compile the model
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.0)
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
model_3.compile(optimizer = opt, loss =loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the model
model_3.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10,validation_data = (X_test,y_test),callbacks= callback_list1)
```

i am designing a tensor flow model and initializer to be used is "he_uniform" and optimizers should be "SGD with momentum" :

i am always getting the error which i am not able to resolve ,the error i got is:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

While I used `random_uniform_initializer(0,1)` by changing no of neurons in each layers as follows 50,100,150,200,250,1 ,the model works.
but `he_uniform_glorotuniform` not working i tried many combination of neurons getting same error

I checked dataset ,it has no nan values or missing values

Comment: May you please post the entire code alone towards the end in using python markdown ? Could be helpful.

Comment: Just a guess but try doing `model_3 = Sequential()` then run `model3.add(Dense(50,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=initializer3,name = "Dense1", input_shape=(2,)))` for the first layer and `model3.add(Dense(___, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer3, name = "DenseX"))` for the remaining.